# How to locate attachment of mouseover event Chrome Debugger

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

i have ajax call that refreshes the product including its image element. After refresh, the product image magnifier does not work. I think its because i need to reattach the event on mouse over of the image element. So, i would like to locate code where the mouse over event is attached initially at load time, so i can reuse that code to reattach event after ajax refresh. I have little experience on client side programming and tools like Chrome developer. Using Chrome Dev tool and Event Listener Breakpoints/load, i am able to stop the code onload, however. With so much info i am still unable to locate the callback function or specifically location in code where the event is being attached to the image element initially. How to do that? what should i look for? Is there better tool or approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [visual event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2), by SpryMedia. It is implemented as a bookmarklet so it is very portable and can easily be used on projects where you do not have convenient access to source files.

From the docs - Visual Event shows:

- Which elements have events attached to them
- The type of events attached to an element
- The code that will be run with the event is triggered
- The source file and line number for where the attached function was defined (Webkit browsers and Opera only).

Comment: Thank You Ethan...i tried on Firefox and had trouble view or find the event handlers which are attached to the document elements. I could see message '1 events were found attached to 1 nodes. 0 events were attached to elements not currently in the document.' but this as far i got